# "Open Existing Project" with Haskell for Mac?

Tags: haskell

Given:

```
$ls 
app         cabal.config        publickey.txt       stack.yaml      test
Store_Locations_Files   app-dev.cfg     privatekey.txt      src         
static          myproject.cabal
```

How can I open this project with the [Haskell for Mac IDE](http://haskellformac.com/)?

Similar to IDEA with Java, I can simply point to either a pom.xml or the folder containing it to open a project.

Does this IDE provide it?

Comment: Is Mac IDE a specific editor?

Comment: @jcolemang [Haskell for Mac](http://haskellformac.com/) is.

Answer (score 2):

Haskell for Mac can currently (version 1.4) not import arbitrary existing Haskell projects. More details are in [this knowledge base article](http://community.hfm.io/hc/en-us/articles/115007207807-How-can-I-import-an-existing-project-).

Comment: Thank you. Given the above project, can I do anything to be able to use Haskell for Mac with my existing project?

Comment: You can rename the directory to add the suffix `hsproj` and try to open it.